# using SudzC on Dynamic TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, soap, sudzc

This is my first time with working on Webservice on Cocoa-touch framework, I am successfully getting data from web-service on console but when i try to pass it on TableView with array , it does not do anything. I think problem is  ,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

That method does not pass on compiler for compile . And even it is going to work , it will get  all off data with tags  to  table text , because using of  : `cell.textLabel.text = [myDataCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

How can i use them on dynamic cell.text with  specified fields ?. Any help will appreciate.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "REQService.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize sorguTextField,sorguButton,sorguLabelOutput,name;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getOutput:(id)sender {

    REQService* service = [REQService service];
    service.logging = YES;

    [service NumaradanIsimALL:self action:@selector(NumaradanIsimALLHandler:) msisdn:sorguTextField.text username: @"xxx" password:@"xxxxxxxxx"];



    myDataCell = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithObjects:myData, nil];

}

#pragma notes - View Tables

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [myDataCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not  implemented the web-service response handler `NumaradanIsimALLHandler` method in your view controller class. Implement this method in your code and once you get a response in this method, assign it to myDataCell object and reload the table view (e.g. `[tableView reloadData]`);

In this case you are making an Asynchronous web-service call on tap of a button, and as table view delegates would get called as soon as the view would load therefore you would need to reload the table view in NumaradanIsimALLHandler handler method.

Comment: I implemented web-service, due to : [service NumaradanIsimALL:self action:@selector(NumaradanIsimALLHandler:) msisdn:sorguTextField.text username: @"xxx" password:@"xxxxxxxxx"]; just works fine and i can trace from Console. Main problem is does not pass to UITableView side ...

Comment: Implement NumaradanIsimALLHandler method in your ViewController class. Once you get a response from server this method would get called automatically. In the same method you can assign the response data to myData array and reload the table view.

Comment: Sandy thank you for your help , I loaded batch data with NSLog(); but what i wanted to do , I need them too add tableview with DeSerialize , But my output seems like that  : <NumaradanIsimALLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><NumaradanIsimALLResult><id>2</id><result_code>1</result_code><count>1</count><name /><surname>KARABAGLAR BELEDIYE BASKANLIGI</surname><city /><town /><msisdn>2324147829</msisdn><opr>TT</opr></NumaradanIsimALLResult></NumaradanIsimALLResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
2012-11-01 09:58:34.386 SudzCExamples[396:11303] <NumaradanIsim><count>0</count></NumaradanIsim>

Comment: I would need sample code files to provide more help. Will you be able to share the same?

Comment: You may download whole code from http://d01.megashares.com/dl/w6IV9oC/sudan.zip , I just put some comments in REQServiceExample.m that you can check it , Also every process occurs in there. If you would help me i will appreciate . Thanks !